# Find duplicate characters in string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to print `duplicate` characters in a string for example if string input is: `"aabacdceefeg"` output should be `a-->3,b-->1,c--->2,e-->3` like this way have to print values but below code not working for this logic can some one suggest me please

```
  public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
             String string1 = "Great responsibility";
      char string[] = string1.toCharArray();
      HashMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
      for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
          for (int j = i + 1; j < string.length; j++) {
              if (string[i] == string[j]) {
                 Integer value = hashMap.get(string[i]);
                 hashMap.put(string[i], value+1);
              } else {
                  hashMap.put(string[i], 1);
              }
          }
      }
      System.out.println(hashMap);
    }

   }
```

Comment: [This](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/find-duplicate-characters/) should probably answer your question.

Comment: The count variable isn't being set correctly.

Comment: You have to reset the count variable to 1 after every iteration

Comment: You will many solutions online for this problem. Just add all characters in the string to the map with count 1. If the character already exists in map, increment the counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many answers how to optimise the solution but there are none to show how the original `O(N^2)` time complexity solution could be fixed.

Here are the things to fix in the original solution (besides the obvious inefficiency)

1. If a character doesn't exist in the map yet then `value` should be set to `1` as that's its first time occurrence.
2. If the current char doesn't equal to another char then keep its original count.

The fixed code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string1 = "Great responsibility";
    char string[] = string1.toCharArray();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < string.length; j++) {
            Integer value = hashMap.get(string[i]);
            if (value == null) {
                value = 1;
            }
            if (string[i] == string[j]) {
                hashMap.put(string[i], value + 1);
            } else {
                hashMap.put(string[i], value);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hashMap);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it by just using the hashMap directly and only using one loop

```
    String string1 = "Great responsibility";

    HashMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (Character c : string1.toCharArray()) {

        if (hashMap.containsKey(c)) {
            int val  = hashMap.get(c);
            hashMap.put(c, val + 1);
        }
        else {
            hashMap.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hashMap);
```

**output**

```
{ =1, a=1, b=1, e=2, G=1, i=3, l=1, n=1, o=1, p=1, r=2, s=2, t=2, y=1}
```

Comment: I have to do this requirement with out hashmap

Comment: Why do **you** have a HashMap in your question.  Why did you not mention this before?  Wasting peoples time.

Comment: Why are you considering `G` and `g` a different character?

Comment: @Anatolii Easy enough to fix if there was a requirement from the OP to treat them the same `String string1 = "Great responsibility".toLowerCase();`

Comment: @ScaryWombat why my above code is not working ?any suggestions

Comment: Because it is wrong.  I have given you a solution above.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one level of loops:

```
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        Integer count = map.get(string[i]);
        if (count == null) {
            map .put(string[i], 1);
        } else {
            map .put(string[i], count+1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have to do this requirement with out hashmap

Comment: Why do **you** have a HashMap in your question.  Why did you not mention this before?  Wasting peoples time.

Comment: @Krish why are you using one then? why have you not stated that constraint in your question?

Answer (score 0):

first create a list of characters and then loop over your desired string.

```
ArrayList<Character> charList=new ArrayList();
charList.clear();

for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {

if(!charList.Contains(string[i])){
charList.add(string[i]))
}

 }

    HashMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (Char char:charList) {
      count=0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < string.length; j++) {
            if (char == string[j]) {
                hashMap.put(char, count++);
            } 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hashMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String string1 = "Great responsibility";
    char[] chars = string1.toCharArray();

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(char c : chars) 
    {
        if(map.containsKey(c)) {
            int counter = map.get(c);
            map.put(c, ++counter);
        } else {
            map.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
```

I hope it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Java8 lambda function** to solve the problem. You can simply convert the String into the count Map.

```
    String string1 = "aabacdceefeg";
    Map<Character,Long> countMap = string1.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())
        );
    System.out.println(countMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Will return the sorted order based on the character count value
String input = "stackoverflow";
Map<Character, Long> result = input.chars().mapToObj(c -> Character.valueOf((char) c))
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new));

//output
result = {a=1, r=1, c=1, t=1, e=1, f=1, v=1, w=1, k=1, l=1, o=2, s=3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Java 8** :

```
    String name = "anandha";
     name.chars()   //returns IntStream 
    .mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch) //returns Stream<Character>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ch -> ch, Collectors.counting())) //returns  Map<Character, Long>
    .forEach((k, v)->{
        System.out.println(k+ " : " + v);
    });
```

**Output**:

```
 a : 3
 d : 1
 h : 1
 n : 2
```